# Optimize O(N^2) to O(N*logN)

Tags: algorithm, sorting, queue, time-complexity, heap

I have been doing an "Algorithms and Data Structures" course recently and have come across an interesting exercise.

Consider a system which has multiple `a` executors, `b` queues and `c` tasks. `a`,`b`,`c` are all below 10^5. In the beginning of the program there is a user input of those three numbers. After that there are `c` lines which describe tasks. Each task is represented by 3 numbers: the time it comes to the system, the queue at which end it stands to and the time it takes to complete.

As for the system itself it works the following way: every second (unit of a time) we must pick a free executor. If there are more than 1, we choose the one with the lower number (every executor has a number from 1 to `a`). After that we must choose a task from the front of some non-empty queue. If at this time there are multiple non-empty queues waiting to get picked, then we pick from the queue which has not been taken from for the longest time by current time (for example, if there are tasks in queues 1 and 2 and before that we have taken from queue 1 at time 3 and from queue 2 at time 1, then we take a task from queue 2). After that the task is assigned to the executor we selected and the executor becomes occupied for the time it takes to complete the task. After that he is ready to take another task (he can do it at the very moment he finishes his current task).

So the final question of the problem is for every task to print which executor will take it for processing and at which moment in time.

Also, the solution must run undex 10 seconds for any input. That makes me think that its time complexity must be below O(N^2). So, I'm thinking about O(N*logN) and actually I'm quite close to it.

So far my solution if the following:
First we select an executor. We can do it in logarithmic time if we use a minimum heap to store executors. To compare executors we can for each of them track time when they get free after completing another task, then compare those times. If the times are equal, then we compare executors' numbers. In the beginning every executor is free at time moment 0 (tasks start to arrive at time moment 1). So then for every task we can pick an executor which will be ready first.

Also we can notice that at any given time moment we don't need all the tasks in all queues, only those at front of each queue. We can store them in an array, let's call it `tasksArray`.

So, we can iterate over every queue and if the task in front is arriving before the picked executor gets free then we store this task in a separate array. This array will contain all the tasks which are able for the taking by the chosen executor as soon as it gets free from his previous task.

In case there are no tasks found that means that the executor has to wait until some tasks come. To determine which tasks will these be we can one again iterate over all queues and find the tasks which arrive soonest. There may be more than one task (2 tasks may arrive at the same time to the different queues), so we store them as an array.

Both described ways of picking tasks are O(N). So far it seems okay.

After choosing tasks using one of the ways above we can sort them by the time it was last taken a task from the queue they come from (task from queue which was waiting for the longest comes first and then comes the task from the second-longest-waiting queue etc)

After that we can go over the sorted `tasksArray` and for every task we assign it to the executor (we picked one in the beginning), the executors gets occupied and we put it back into the executors heap with an updated time record, which indicates the moment it gets free. Then for each next element of the `tasksArray` we get an executor from the heap and assign the task to it and so it goes until the `tasksArray` is empty. Such iteration is O(N*logN). So far the solution is O(N+N*logN).

After all tasks from `tasksArray` are assigned to their executors we acquire the next batch of the tasks from the front of the queues and everything goes on again. That continues until all queues are empty.

This solution can be considered O(N*logN), however this solution is incorrect.

Lets go back to the case when the executor has gotten ready but there are no tasks yet. In this case it waits until the first tasks from one or multiple queues at the same time come and picks one of them. But while it waits, other executors may finish their tasks and become ready. Some of those executors may have a smaller number than the one we picked. So, here comes the problem, because in such case we must pick the one with the smallest number, however my solution doesn't do it.

And there is a reason for that. If we store executors in a heap, then we cannot know which executors have become ready while we were waiting. To determine this we will need to check every executor in the heap and compare its 'ready-time' with the current time. However, such check gives us O(N) time (we can iterate over the underlying array of the queue, not the queue itself since we need to check all the tasks anyway). In the worst case when there comes only 1 task every 2 seconds and it has a small processing time of 1 second, then we will fall into the situation of executors waiting for each task. And for each task we will iterate over all executors. Such algorithm is O(N*N) = O(N^2) which is unacceptable because of time limits.

And this is where I am stuck. I cannot find a way to determine whether more executors have become ready while we were waiting for the task in time under O(N). I have also been thinking about changing the data structure from heap to some other structure, but that gives me no luck either.

So is there any way this exercise can be solved in under O(N^2) time?

Comment: What is `N`? If it's the `10^5` value you mention, then my imaginary supercomputer can definitely solve whatever the problem is (which I didn't understand since there is no problem statement, just a description of a system) using a `O(N^2)` algorithm in under 10 seconds.

Comment: @Nelfeal thanks for your reply! You are right, I forgot to write the problem itself. It is the following: for every task to print which executor will take it for processing and at which moment in time.
I have also edited my question accordingly

Comment: As for the N in O(N), it is the amount of iterations I make on the array. In case when I was describing picking tasks N is the amount of tasks, it is denoted by `c`, as for picking executors N is the amount of executors, it is denoted by `a`

Comment: Also, the checking system ,unfortunately, has no super-computer and the solution with O(N^2) complexity takes about 20 seconds there which fails the time limit, so I need to speed my solution up

Comment: You can't have multiple values for N. I assume you mean it's the limit such that a, b, and c are all under N. My point is that having `N=10^5` makes the algorithm complexity a moot point, since `O(f(10^5)) = O(1)`, no matter the function `f`.

Comment: My guess for solving your issue would be to make one heap for the free executors, ordered by identifier, and another for the busy ones, with the same order you are using (and that you forgot to mention but implied to be the time at which the executor got its most recent task). When an executor becomes free, remove it from the busy heap and add it to the free heap (these are both `O(log n)` operations). That way you only ever pick the free executor with the lowest identifier.

Comment: @Nelfeal that's a very promising idea with 2 different heaps. However, how do I know when the executor becomes free? As I see it, I will need to go down the occupied heap checking every entry for whether it has become free. And that makes me iterate over the whole array of executors in the worst case

Comment: Change the ordering of the busy heap to be the time at which the executor finishes its task (the time at which the corresponding task appears plus the time it takes to complete). This way the top of the busy heap will always be the next executor to become free. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Nelfeal lets say that there 3 executors. We have picked #3 and it starts waiting for the task. Executor #1 and #2 are currently busy, #1 will get free in 4 seconds and #2 will get free in 3 seconds. So both #1 and #2 are in the occupied heap right now. A task has come 5 seconds has passed, so all the occupied executors are free now and should be moved to the free heap. But how do I move them? I think I need to do something like `while occupiedHeap.Pop().isFreeNow() { free.Push(executor) }`. In the worst case this means checking the whole occupied heap which is O(N*logN), N is the heap length

Comment: We can assume from the beginning that the whole occupied heap is free now (the worst case) and then we can iterate over underlying heap array which makes it O(N), N is the length of the array. However, we might need to do it for every task and that makes the algorithm O(c*a) where `c` is amount of tasks, `a` is amount of executors, which is too long

Comment: If you need to check the whole busy heap, it means you took care of that number of tasks. You can only do that so many times. Imagine you receive tasks in groups of `c/p`, separated in time such that no two tasks from different groups are executed at the same time. Placing one group into the busy heap takes `O(c/p log c/p)`. Removing one group from it also takes `O(c/p log c/p)`. You only have to do that `p` times, meaning the overall complexity is `O(c log c/p)`. I can't think of a set of tasks that leads to more than `O(N log N)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not fully specified the problem for ties.  For example if a task arrives to an empty queue that has not been picked from for a long time at the same moment that an executor comes free, does that task get assigned to the executor?  Or does some other task get assigned to that executor and the task gets assigned to the next executor to come free?

I'll assume it gets assigned to the executor, and won't deal with other ties.  But you should think through that carefully in your solution.

We need the following heaps.

1. `free_executor` so we can pick the free executor with the lowest numbers.
2. `nonempty_queue` so we can pick from the queue that has been waiting longest.
3. Event. An event has a time, type, and information.  The types are `TaskArrival` and `ExecutorFinished`.  The order is time, then type (with `TaskArrival` first).

And now with that, here is the logic.

```
while events has stuff:
    event = next event
    if event.type = TaskArrival:
        if its queue was empty:
            add its queue to nonempty_queue
        add task to its queue
    else:
        add newly freed executor to free_executor

    if free_executor and nonempty_queue both have something:
        executor = free_executor.pop()
        queue = nonempty_queue.pop()
        task = queue.pop()
        mark that executor did task
        add new event to events queue for executor coming free after task is done
        if queue is not empty:
            put queue back into nonempty_queue with new priority
```

We will generate 2 events per task.  Every operation inside of the loop takes `O(1)` (eg `mark that executor did task`) or `O(log(n))` (eg `queue = nonempty_queue.pop()`).  There are a fixed number of operations per event. Therefore the algorithm runs in time `O(n log(n))`.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Your idea has actually worked for this task. That is intersting that I haven't even thought about event-based solution. Guess I do it next time a see a problem about sequential events :)